# how to run multiple instances of Babylon dictionary in Windows?

Tags: windows

I want to run two instances or more of Babylon dictionary software on windows. I want to install different sets of dictionaries in each and use them as needed. Is there any solution to that? I am using version 7 of babylon.

The software does not allow more than one installation and more than one running instance.
Thanks

Comment: "The software does not allow more than one installation and more than one running instance. " The answer is clearly no then.

Comment: is there any workaround?